# ¿permite numero decimales incluido 0 incial?

Tags: jquery

estoy usando esta expresion regular para permitir números decimales, pero tengo un inconveniente que cuanto coloco un valor como 0.3, 0.8 es decir cuando el cero esta al incicio la marca como invalidad.
estoy usando bootstrapValidator. link:http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/getting-started/

```
$('.registerForm').bootstrapValidator({
    live: 'enabled',
    fields: {
        newinputclrRchiller3: {
            validators: {
                stringLength: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 11,
                    message: 'LONGITUD MÁXIMA ES DE 11 Y MÍNIMA DE 1'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^(\d+\.?\d{0,9}|\.\d{1,9})$/,
                    message: 'SOLO SE PERMITEN NÚMEROS O NÚMEROS DECIMALES (DOS DÍGITOS DESPUÉS DE LA COMA)'
                }
            }
        }


    }
});
```

tambien estoy haciendo esa validación desde PHP, cómo seria la expresion usando php.
gracias por sus respuestas.

**RESPUESTA**

en el input html tenia min="1", la expresion que publique funciona correctamente, en realidad fue error mio, llevaba tiempo con este error y no habia notado que estaba definiendo un valor minimo (quiza porque tengo varios atributos en ese input no habia notado ese atributo).

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$
```

- **[0-9]**: Dígitos del 0 al 9.
- **+**: Cuantificador que permite uno o más dígitos.
- **[,]**: Una coma luego de los dígitos numéricos anteriores.
- **?**: Hace match con uno o más dígitos.

Esto haría match, por ejemplo, con lo siguiente:

```
2,2
3
2,22
5,2312
```

Si luego quisieras que acepte decimales con punto y/o coma:

```
^[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?$
```

Haría match con punto y con coma:

```
2.342
```

Si solo quieres que se haga match cuando haya uno o dos dígitos luego de la coma puedes usar `{1,2}`:

```
^[0-9]+([.,][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Haría match con solo uno o dos dígitos después de la coma, ejemplo:

```
2.32
2,42
5.3
6,2
```

Un ejemplo básico en PHP:

**Código**:

```
<?php

$regex = '/^[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?$/';

if (preg_match($regex, '0,33')) {
    echo "1: Match \n";
}
if (preg_match($regex, '0.33')) {
    echo "2: Match \n";
}
if (preg_match($regex, 'Texto')) {
    echo "3: Match \n";
}
```

**Resultado**:

```
$ -> php b.php

1: Match 
2: Match
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [0-9] equivale a "\d". Puedes utilizar el que prefieras: (\d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

Comment: estoy obteniendo el mismo resultado que la expresion que publique en la pregunta. necesito que me permite tambien digitos como este 0.9, 0.2, etc

Comment: A mitad de la pregunta coloco la siguiente expresión regular: ^[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?$ Que a diferencia de la que coloco al inicio funciona tanto con comas como con puntos. Te edito la pregunta con un ejemplo en PHP.

Comment: acabo de darme cuenta de problema que tenia, en el input html tenia min="1", la expresion que publique funciona correctamente, en realidad fue error mio, llevaba tiempo con este error y no habia notado que esta definiendo un valor minimo.

Comment: Sí, tu expresión regular valida. Lo único que solo te valida con punto pero es solo cuestión de añadir la coma. Lo bueno es siempre hacerla lo más simplificada y correcta posible, adaptando la restricción a lo que necesites. Saludos.

Comment: probe tu expresion pero esta nunca me valida la coma, me sigue validando con el punto y solo con el punto. no sé si falta halgo en la expresion o puede ser problema de bootstrapValidator.

Comment: Por supuesto tienes que tener en cuenta si estás haciendo comprobaciones multi-line, tienes que ser del tipo /m al final. Pero para una sola cosa que valides funciona. Lo puedes ver tanto en el código PHP en su salida como en la imagen que te añadí en la edición. Quizá pueda ser lo que comentas del bootstrapValidator. Saludos.

Comment: si quiero permitir tambien decimales negavtios como seria la expresion?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo añadiendo al principio un guión y luego ? para hacerlo opcional. Quedaría así (sin comillas): "^-?[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?$"